# substitutefont result and \f@family

Tags: fonts, substitution, fontfamily

Is there any way to retrieve the resulting font family of `substitutefont`, e.g. with `\f@family`? It seems that `\f@family` is not affected by `\substitutefont{<encoding>}{<family>}{<new-family>}` statement? The substitution itself is successful, though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T2A}{lmr}{cmr}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
T1/lmr as expected: \f@encoding/\f@family

\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont
T2A/cmr wanted, but T2A/lmr got instead: \f@encoding/\f@family
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Kind regards, Ivan

**EDIT 1**

So, based on the answer and more comments below, it seems I should change the approach in order to get `cmr` from `\f@family`.

Actually, this is what I really want to achieve (WYSIWYM):

- If `T1` font encoding is being used, `lmr` (and other LM families) should be used so that `\f@family` also expands to `lmr`.
- If `T2A` font encoding is being used, `cmr` (and other CM families) should be used *so that `\f@family` also expands to `cmr`*.

The original approach obviously does not satisfy the part in italic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the family by switching to the desired font and splitting up its name with the `\split@name` macro in the kernel.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{lmr}{cmr}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printcurrentfont}{%
  \begingroup\escapechar=\m@ne
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\split@name\expandafter\string\the\font\@nil
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  Encoding: & \f@encoding \\
  Family:   & \f@family \\
  Series:   & \f@series \\
  Shape:    & \f@shape
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\encodingfamily}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \fontencoding{#1}\selectfont
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\split@name\expandafter\string\the\font\@nil
  \f@family
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

T1: \encodingfamily{T1}; T2A: \encodingfamily{T2A}

\bigskip

\csname f@family\endcsname\qquad
\printcurrentfont

\bigskip

\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont

\csname f@family\endcsname\qquad
\printcurrentfont

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, `\f@family` records the default value “lmr”, but the font uses the right name “cmr”. This is why groups are necessary in the two macros that exploit `\split@name` that redefines `\f@...` based on the font selector obtained with `\the\font`.

Note: see edit history for a previous solution using the `substitutefont` package, now declared obsolete.

Comment: Is it really the active family, as far as LaTeX is concerned? I thought not because the font is defined as part of the `lmr` family by the substitution. So `\f@family`, it seems to me, gives the correct result.

Comment: @cfr That's why I access to the font selector command, which, for the T2A encoded upright font is `\T2A/cmr/m/n/10`, as instructed by the (modified) `\DeclareFontShape` declaration.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm still not clear quite what the OP's purpose is, so I'm not clear what's wanted. (I thought I understood when I answered the original version of the question, but now I'm much less certain about the edited one.)

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the prompt update!

Answer (score 5):

The font family returned is correct.

A font family for LaTeX is declared with

```
\DeclareFontFamily{<encoding>}{<family name>}{}
```

Fonts are then assigned to the family using

```
\DeclareFontShape{<encoding>}{<family name>}{<series>}{<shape>}{
    <-> <TeX font name>
}{}
```

or

```
\DeclareFontShape{<encoding>}{<family name>}{<series>}{<shape>}{<->ssub * <same or other family name>/<same or other series>/<same or other shape>}{}
```

or similar.

`<->ssub` indications a 'silent substitution'. It is commonly used to silently substitute one font series for another or one font shape for another. For example,

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{yrd}{m}{si}{<->ssub * yrd/m/sc}{}
```

Substitutes whichever font is defined in the specification of the `yrd/m/sc` shape for any attempt to use the `yrd/m/si` shape in the T1 encoding. This is because the latter does not otherwise exist - there is no small-caps italic in this font. Hence, small-caps upright is used instead. Similarly,

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{yrd}{b}{it}{<->ssub * yrd/db/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{yrd}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * yrd/b/it}{}
```

result in silent substitution of the font defined as `yrd/db/it` if either `yrd/b/it` or `yrd/bx/it` is called. This means that the demi-bold will be used when bold or bold-extended is requested for italic `yrd` in the T1 encoding. This is because this family only has demi-bold and medium, so `\bfseries` would not behave as expected.

Now consider the line

```
\substitutefont{T2A}{lmr}{cmr}
```

This is equivalent to

```
\DeclareFontFamily{T2A}{lmr}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lmr}{m}{n}{<->ssub * cmr/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lmr}{m}{it}{<->ssub * cmr/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lmr}{m}{sl}{<->ssub * cmr/m/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lmr}{m}{sc}{<->ssub * cmr/m/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lmr}{b}{n}{<->ssub * cmr/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lmr}{b}{it}{<->ssub * cmr/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lmr}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * cmr/b/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lmr}{b}{sc}{<->ssub * cmr/b/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lmr}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * cmr/bx/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lmr}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * cmr/bx/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lmr}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * cmr/bx/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * cmr/bx/sc}{}
```

That is, as far as LaTeX is concerned, there is a `T2A/lmr` family. That family is defined to use the same fonts as are specified for the corresponding `T2A/cmr` family, but that doesn't mean that the latter *family* is substituted for the former. It rather means that the former family is constructed and that fonts which also belong to the `cmr` family in this encoding are substituted silently whenever the various series and shapes are requested for the `lmr` family in T2A.

Hence, the name of the font family is returned accurately. The fact that the fonts which constitute that family also belong to another font family isn't relevant, because you have requested the `lmr` family and *not* the `cmr` family for T2A.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent explanation! So, if I understood correctly (keep in mind I use `pdflatex`):
1. With `substitutefont` the silent substitutions are made, and there is no way to retrieve the "original"?
2. In order to produce the same output in font context but get what I really wanted with `\f@family`, I should avoid `substitutefont` package and not implement "fallback to `cmr` for `T2A`" like above (and other CM families, not in MWE), but properly "change both font encoding and font family" (for the Cyrillic script) like this `\fontencoding{T2A}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont`.

Comment: @IvanKokan You might be able to get the name of the specific TeX font. I'm not sure about that. But there is no 'original' family i.e. the document never requests the font family `T2A/cmr` and LaTeX never uses it. It isn't the family that is substituted. Rather various fonts are substituted for the `T2A/lmr`. `T2A/cmr` doesn't exist so far as this document is concerned. And, yes, this is the effect of `substitutefont`. So if getting `T2A/cmr` from `\f@encoding\f@family` is really needed (but why?), then you need another approach.

Comment: [`T2A/cmr` is probably the fallback family for that encoding. However, you never use it.]

Comment: `T2A/cmr` is indeed the fallback family (if no substitution is made on my own, I get such warnings). My goal of getting `T2A/cmr` was deeper understanding of the matter.

Comment: @IvanKokan Re. your edit, are you sure this is what you need? You now have answers which extract the `cmr` from the font name. Does it really matter if the active family is `T2A/lmr` rather than `T2A/cmr`?

Answer (score 5):

cfr explains in his answer how `\substitutefont` is implemented using `ssub`.
But even after a `ssub`, there is a way to find the family name of the substituted font: If the actually loaded font was loaded by NFSS, the font command looks like `\T2A/cmr/m/n/10`, so all the information is encoded in the name of the font command. It can be extracted by splitting this name into its components:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T2A}{lmr}{cmr}

\def\realfamilyhelper#1/#2/#3\relax{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax
    \GenericError{(realfamily)\space\space}{NFSS is not active, unable to get family}{}{}%
  \else
    #2%
  \fi
}
\newcommand\realfamily{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \realfamilyhelper
  \expandafter\string\the\font
  //\relax
}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
T1/lmr as expected: \f@encoding/\realfamily

\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont
T2A/cmr as expected: \f@encoding/\realfamily
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]